# jQuery radio button form default

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I have a jQuery function that auto-fills and makes element read only when a radio button is clicked. I would like for this to be upon page load. Is there a way to default this upon page load?

```
$('#Radio1').click(function() {
            $('#emenent').val("My Value");
            $('#element').prop("readonly", true);
    });
```

Adding 'checked' to the radio element only checks the button, but does not execute the function. Appreciate the help!

Comment: you should check if radio button is checked.

Answer (score 1):

When the document loads, you can set the property.  Is this what you mean?

```
$(function() {
    $('#element').prop('readonly',true);
});
```

This will set the value of readonly of #element to true whenever the page loads.

Comment: Yes indeed, this along with the checked element. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Put it in the document.ready handler:

```
$(function () {
    $('#element').val("My Value").prop("readonly", true);
});
```

To avoid repeating the code in both places, put it in a function:

```
function makeElementReadonly() {
    $('#element').val("My Value").prop("readonly", true);
}

$(function() {
    makeElementReadOnly();
    $('#Radio1').click(makeElementReadOnly);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Write below code before .click() function call and it will work on page load

```
$(document).ready(function() {
      alert("On load occurred!");
      $( "#Radio1" ).click();
});
```